# Mean per group in a column, result per row

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have this data frame *(adjusted from @Vinterwoo's code)*, and I'm looking for a function to get the mean per group for each column. So the mean for group A in column C1 and C2, and the same for group B etcetera. I know how to get the mean per group (e.g. using `aggregate`) but I need the mean to show in every row of the corresponding group (please see desired output).

```
C1 <- c(3,2,4,3,6,7,5)
C2 <- c(3,7,3,4,5,2,1)
DF <- data.frame(ID=c("A","C","A","C","E","F","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2)

ID C1 C2
A  3  3
C  2  7
A  4  3
C  3  4
E  6  5
F  7  2
E  5  1
```

Desired output:

```
ID C1 C2 avg.C1 avg.C2
A  3  3    3.5    3.0
C  2  7    2.5    5.5
A  4  3    3.5    3.0
C  3  4    2.5    5.5
E  6  5    5.5    3.0
F  7  2    7.0    2.0
E  5  1    5.5    3.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the "data.table" package for this:

```
sdcols <- names(DF)[-1]      ## A vector of the new columns we want to add
as.data.table(DF)[, paste(sdcols, "mean", sep = "_") := lapply(.SD, mean), 
                  by = ID][] ## you can also be more specific and specify sdcols
#    ID C1 C2 C1_mean C2_mean
# 1:  A  3  3     3.5     3.0
# 2:  C  2  7     2.5     5.5
# 3:  A  4  3     3.5     3.0
# 4:  C  3  4     2.5     5.5
# 5:  E  6  5     5.5     3.0
# 6:  F  7  2     7.0     2.0
# 7:  E  5  1     5.5     3.0
```

---

As indicated in the commented code, you can specify which columns to act on using the `.SDcols` argument:

```
sdcols <- names(DF)[-1]
as.data.table(DF)[, paste(sdcols, "mean", sep = "_") := lapply(.SD, mean), 
                  by = ID, .SDcols = sdcols][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(avg.C1 = mean(C1), avg.C2 = mean(C2))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
#Groups: ID
#
#  ID C1 C2 avg.C1 avg.C2
#1  A  3  3    3.5    3.0
#2  C  2  7    2.5    5.5
#3  A  4  3    3.5    3.0
#4  C  3  4    2.5    5.5
#5  E  6  5    5.5    3.0
#6  F  7  2    7.0    2.0
#7  E  5  1    5.5    3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate and merge as the following

```
DF2=aggregate(cbind(C1, C2) ~ ID , data= DF , FUN= mean)
DF_Wanted= merge(DF, DF2, by=c("ID"), all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to create a new column using `base` you can simply calculate the desired values and assign them to the columns. To calculate that, you take the mean of each C that has ID equal to its own:

```
DF$avg.C1 <- sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i) mean(DF$C1[DF$ID==DF$ID[i]]))
DF$avg.C2 <- sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i) mean(DF$C2[DF$ID==DF$ID[i]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers already posted, but I'm surprised no one mentioned [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html), which is basically designed for this exact purpose; it even runs `mean()` without any prodding!

```
cbind(DF,avg.C1=ave(DF$C1,DF$ID),avg.C2=ave(DF$C2,DF$ID));
##   ID C1 C2 avg.C1 avg.C2
## 1  A  3  3    3.5    3.0
## 2  C  2  7    2.5    5.5
## 3  A  4  3    3.5    3.0
## 4  C  3  4    2.5    5.5
## 5  E  6  5    5.5    3.0
## 6  F  7  2    7.0    2.0
## 7  E  5  1    5.5    3.0
```